# HTML and CSS: placing the Google +1 button makes it impossible to add space between elements

Tags: html, css, google-plus

I tried adding this snippet to my html page:

```
<!-- Place this tag where you want the +1 button to render. -->
<div class="g-plusone" data-size="tall" data-annotation="inline" data-width="300"></div>

<div style="background-color: red; float:left; padding-left: 125px; margin-left: 125px;">
<!-- Place this tag after the last +1 button tag. -->
<script type="text/javascript">
  (function() {
    var po = document.createElement('script'); po.type = 'text/javascript'; po.async = true;
    po.src = 'https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);
  })();
</script>
</div>
```

And it placed the +1 button there, but did not put any white space to the left of the button. I am testing it on this page:
http://www.problemio.com/business/how_to_get_business_ideas.php

So you can see that all the other social buttons have a space between them, but the +1 button does not.

Would anyone know how I can add the space?

Thanks,
Alex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`margin-left: 25px` on the table with id `#plusone_table` should do the trick.